# Retrieve element from post data with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, select, http-post

**Note: With the help of some comments it seems like this is most likely not possible**

I'm using a jQuery ajax call to send an e-mail address, in the called PHP file I return an error or success message depending on the outcome.

Now I want to alert this outcome after my jQuery `$.post` is successful, the problem is that the called PHP file includes a config file that also has a Javascript file, so my data will look like this:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="x.js"></script>Message`

So I tried the following:

**Data**

`<script type="text/javascript"> src="x.js"></script><p>Message</p>`

And I tried two different things within my `$.post`:

**Post**

```
$.post('ajax.php',function(data){

    alert($(data).find('p'));
    // this returns [object Object]

    alert($(data).find('p').html());
    // this returns null?

}
```

The fact that `alert($(data).find('p'));` returns `[object Object]` leads me to think it is working, but then I don't understand why `.html()` returns `null`. If I check `data` through firebug it shows exactly what I typed above.

**Some extra information**

`console.log(data)`

returns

`<script type="text/javascript"> src="x.js"></script><p>Message</p>`

---

`console.log($(data).find('p'))` returns a jQuery object.

---

`console.log($(data).find('p').length);` returns `0`

---

```
$('html').append(data);
console.log($('p').html());`
```

returns `Message` as expected.

**Final edit**

I didn't think about the fact that the `$` in `$(data).find('p')` is probably why it's returning `[object Object]`.

Now that I think about it, it seems quite obvious it's impossible to do what I am asking because I am trying to use jQuery's selector engine on a string. I'll change my document structure to remove the JS reference from my config file instead.

Comment: why is the PHP page writing out a JS reference if it's not being used?

Comment: Can you post the data coming back via ajax (using firebug etc)? Also can try adding `alert($(data).find('p').length);`  and update the post with result?

Comment: What does `console.log(data)` contain, and what does `console.log($(data).find('p'))` contain?

Comment: @Fosco, because the JS reference is used by all the other pages that require the same config file. @Niklas, `console.log(data)` contains what I typed under data in my question (like I said), `console.log($(data).find('p'))` returns a jQuery object. @Cybernate, `console.log($(data).find('p').length);` returns 0.

Comment: @Bless Yahu, I would definitely say so if jQuery is able to to parse `$(data).find('p')` into a jQuery object. The `typeof` for `data` is `string` but isn't that always the case?

Comment: i'm not quite sure you can convert it this way and use find. try attaching it to the dom tree so it could be parsed naturally. Try to append it. $(..) always return jQuery object because $ is the jQuery object, also find is empty collection that extends $ and it will be object too

Comment: When adding `$('html').append(data);console.log($('p').html());` it returns `Message` as expected. I guess then maybe it's not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use selectors you first need that string to be part of the DOM tree. $(data) does not do it
automatically, you need to append it to an element (like body) or to replace an existing one.

```
onComplete: function(content) {
 content.find("#whatever"); // won't work
 $("#existingElement").html(content);
 $("#existingElement").find("#whatever"); // works
}
```

Comment: I know. The whole idea was retrieving `p` directly from `data`.

Answer (score -1):

just echo it out in PHP

```
alert(<?php echo $_POST['variable']; ?>);
```

Comment: I'm sure his final intention is not to have the variable `alerted`

Comment: Even if it was, it's a .js file so it won't be parsed by PHP. And even if it was it wouldn't contain a variable that has yet to be retrieved through my ajax call.

Comment: Oh well I am sorry mr Kokos. I was only trying to help. Please forgive me if I have made a mistake.

Comment: I'm sorry if my comment sounded demeaning, but your answer wasn't thought through.